# How can I convert set of if conditions with async method calls to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, async-await

I've got some method calls looking like this

```
if (SectionContainedWithin(args, RegisterSection.StudentPersonalData))
    schoolRegister.StudentPersonalData = await _sectionGeneratorsProvider.StudentPersonalDataGenerator.GenerateAsync(args);

if (SectionContainedWithin(args, RegisterSection.StudentAttendances))
    schoolRegister.StudentAttendances = await _sectionGeneratorsProvider.StudentMonthAttendancesGenerator.GenerateAsync(args);

if (SectionContainedWithin(args, RegisterSection.Grades))
    schoolRegister.Grades = await _sectionGeneratorsProvider.GradesGenerator.GenerateAsync(args);

// More generating here ...
```

Every `GenerateAsync` produces object of different type.

```
public interface IGenerator<TResult, in TArgs>
{
    Task<TResult> GenerateAsync(TArgs args);
}
```

How can I rewrite those `if`s so I could define a list of actions and conditions and then iterate through them.
Something like:

```
var sections = new Dictionary<bool, Func<Task>>()
{
    { 
        SectionContainedWithin(args, RegisterSection.StudentPersonalData),
        () => schoolRegister.StudentPersonalData = await _sectionGeneratorsProvider.StudentPersonalDataGenerator.GenerateAsync(args);
    },

    // More generating here ...
}

foreach(var item in sections)
{
    if(item.Key)
    {
        await item.Value();
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @peter-duniho answer I dropped idea of creating `Dictionary<bool, Func<Task>>` and replaced it with `IReadOnlyDictionary<RegisterSection, Func<RegisterXml, RegisterGenerationArgs, Task>>` since it makes more sense.
Multiple keys, not only two true/false.

So thats what I ended up with

```
private IReadOnlyDictionary<RegisterSection, Func<RegisterXml, RegisterGenerationArgs, Task>> CreateSectionActionsDictionary()
{
    return new Dictionary<RegisterSection, Func<RegisterXml, RegisterGenerationArgs, Task>>
    {
        { RegisterSection.RegisterCover, async(reg, args) => reg.Cover = await _sectionGenerators.RegisterCoverGenerator.GenerateAsync(args) },
        { RegisterSection.StudentPersonalData, async(reg, args) => reg.StudentPersonalData = await _sectionGenerators.StudentPersonalDataGenerator.GenerateAsync(args)},

        // Add more generating here ...
    };
}

private async Task GenerateSectionsAsync(RegisterGenerationArgs args, RegisterXml reg)
{
    foreach (var sectionAction in SectionActions)
        if (SectionContainedWithin(args, sectionAction.Key))
            await sectionAction.Value(reg, args);

}
```

Comment: You're almost there, you just need to make the lambdas `async`.

Comment: @svick: not really. It's true that making the lambdas `async` is required, but there are more fundamental issues with the dictionary: evaluating the `SectionContainedWithin()` method when populating the dictionary not only assumes that `args` is known at that time, but also that only two items will ever be in the dictionary at a time, and only one of those will have a key value of `true`. See my posted answer for more specifics.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right, I didn't realize the `Dictionary` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code example correctly, a dictionary really isn't the right tool for this job. You appear to be using it only to store pairs of values; you're not using the primary feature of a dictionary, which is to be able to map a key value you already know to another value.

In addition, the code example you are proposing won't work because you need the `args` value in order to evaluated the `SectionContainedWithin()` call. Even if you were trying to declare the dictionary in a context where `args` is valid and can be used to initialize the dictionary, you would have the problem that it makes the key type `bool`, which would mean you could only have two entries in the dictionary at most, and would have no way to actually handle all of the combinations where the `SectionContainedWithin()` method returned `true`.

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're doing, it's impossible to know for sure what exactly you need. But it will look something like this:

```
struct SectionGenerator<TArgs>
{
    public readonly RegisterSection RegisterSection;
    public readonly Func<TArgs, Task> Generate;

    public SectionGenerator(RegisterSection registerSection, Func<TArgs, Task> generate)
    {
        RegisterSection = registerSection;
        Generate = generate;
    }
}

SectionGenerator<TArgs>[] generators =
{
    new SectionGenerator<TArgs>(RegisterSection.StudentPersonalData,
        async args => schoolRegister.StudentPersonalData = await _sectionGeneratorsProvider.StudentPersonalDataGenerator.GenerateAsync(args);
    // etc.
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach (SectionGenerator<TArgs> generator in generators)
{
    if (SectionContainedWithin(args, generator.RegisterSection))
    {
        await generator.Generate(args);
    }
}
```

Assuming it's reasonable for all these async operations to be in progress concurrently, you could even do something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(generators
    .Where(g => SectionContainedWithin(args, g.RegisterSection))
    .Select(g => g.Generate(args));
```

Comment: You're right, in this case dictionary is not the best collection type to be considered. Rather I'd use `IEnumerable<Tuple<bool, Func<Task>>>` or create new `class` to store `bool` and `func` pair. I'm going to change that!

About providing _MCV code example_, first solution (set of `if`s) works and is the most obvious approach I can imagine. Altough it's kind of hard to maintain.

I'll come back to this question tomorow. Thanks!

Comment: @pizycki: I don't understand the point of storing a `bool` value. If you're able to evaluate the method call, then you've got the `args` value in hand and can just go ahead and call the appropriate `GenerateAsync()` method. The only thing you need to store in that case are the tasks returned. If you don't have the `args` value in hand, then there's no way to get the `bool` value. Either way, storing a `bool` in your collection makes no sense.

Comment: You're right, it makes no sense to me neither now. Thank you for pointing this out.